# Links / URLs containing special characters are not recognized by markdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, hyperlinks

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876/infimum-of-some-quantities), I linked to some page within the Wolfram alpha site, and the links did not appear. For example, I will try to link the last word in this [sentence](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[%281%2Be%5E%28-%282%29v%29%29%5E%28-2%29+%2B+%282%29+%281%2Be%5Ev%29%5E%28-2%29%2C+%7Bt%2C-0.5%2C+0.5%7D]). Here is the URL I was trying to link to

`http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[%281%2Be^%28-%282%29v%29%29^%28-2%29+%2B+%282%29+%281%2Be^v%29^%28-2%29%2C+{t%2C-0.5%2C+0.5}]`

I suspect the problem is that Wolfram alpha uses square brackets in its URLs. If this could be fixed, it would be nice.

Comment: I am calling this `status-bydesign` because it is not really a bug, just how these special characters are treated. If you want to request better parsing for URLs, repost on [meta.stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) as a `feature-request`, but I guess that the stackexchange team will decline/defer it since a reasonable workaround exists.

Comment: @Kaestur: At least for this user, it should be solvable by http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60211/auto-escape-url-when-entering-with-hyperlink-button-ctrll. I hope it won't be `[status-declined]` :)

Comment: "it is not really a bug, just how these special characters are treated" — I don't get it. These special characters are being treated not the way we want, so it *is* a bug. ("That's how it's implemented" is not the same as "That's how it's designed".)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: those special characters are not technically allowed to be in URLs (not just an issue of what the site will accept).  I think the best solution is probably the one suggested on meta.SO (KennyTM's link, above).

Comment: How can this be by design? Is forcing users to use silly tools like URL encoders to write links to Wikipedia (of all places!) part of the design?! If the *design* does not contemplate making it easier for users to provide information, well, I am sure someone can come up with a better design!

Comment: @Isaac: those characters are not allowed in a technical sense, but humans do write them. Since this software is intended to be user by humans...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since this was asked, we have improved <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> aka the link toolbar button to encode any oddball characters in links inserted into posts:

[The Wolfram Alpha link from above](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%281%2be%5E%28-%282%29v%29%29%5E%28-2%29%20%2b%20%282%29%20%281%2be%5Ev%29%5E%28-2%29,%20%7Bt,-0.5,%200.5%7D%5D)

Note that it is properly encoded, etc.

Some browsers also now automatically "fix" these oddball characters **when copying from the address bar** by encoding them on your behalf. A few tests with `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning–Kruger_effect` produced...

- Chrome 14: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect`
- Firefox 6: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect`
- IE 9: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning–Kruger_effect`
- Opera 11.5: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning–Kruger_effect`
- Safari 5.05: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning–Kruger_effect`

So Chrome and Firefox have the most desirable behavior here, IMO.

Comment: For Firefox 6.0.2 this is *almost* true. If you make any edits in the address bar before you copy and paste (even if you restore the edit), then the pasted version will no longer be encoded. I experienced this with my fat fingers trying to hit CTRL+C and missing.

Answer (score 6):

Two more workarounds:
Use a tool like [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) to encode the URLs
Use a URL shortening service like [this](http://tinyurl.com/)

The second one is less good, because it relies on an outside party to guarantee that your answer/comment continues to make sense.

Answer (score 4):

I've fixed your links.

Many special characters need to be escaped, e.g. `Plot[x^2,{x,-1,1}]`, the link http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[x^2%2C{x%2C-1%2C1}] won't be recognized, because `^`, `{` and `}` are special characters and need to be escaped, like http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5Bx%5E2%252C%7Bx%252C-1%252C1%7D%5D.